# variadic scanf in C

Tags: c, parsing, list, scanf, variadic-functions

I was curious if it's possible to implement a sort of variadic version of `scanf` in C. What I mean is if the input is `push (1 2 3)`, `scanf` would be able to parse that into `%s %d %d %d` with something like `scanf("%s (%d)", string, some_list)`.

It would take all instances of `%d` and append them (in order) to the list...

Am I talking sense?

EDIT: For the specified input, `string == "push"` and `some_list == [1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't [vscanf, vssscanf, vsfcanf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf#vscanf.2C_vsscanf.2C_and_vfscanf) is what you are looking for? They are avaialble from C99 onwards.

Here is a decription and example of usage of [vscanf](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/rzan5mst304.htm) function. Note that C being a compiled and a strongly typed language, you need to give format specifiers properly. Doing something like what higher languages dos is going to involve more work (but is possible because features are inturn written in C).

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how `vscanf` works, and if it suits my purpose. Would it read however many `int`s there are and plop them into a specified array?

Comment: Updated the answer with an usage example.

Comment: How does that example differ from regular scanf?

Comment: I need a variable amount of integers to be scanned and turned into an array :-/

Comment: yeah I got it. Perhaps you should look at source of a higher level language which does it (with the underlying implementation in C), something that treats everything as a `void *` ptr and stores those references in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You could implement a version of scanf that worked like this.

The reason it isn't part of the C library is that it would require data structures that aren't built in to the library. Like a linked-list, or a resizable array.

But anyway, you could make a scanf function that accepted an advanced form of patterns. It could look like `super_scanf("%{s:allocate} (%{d*:array,append)", &string, &array)`

But normally, you either write your own tokenizer and simple parser or you move up to something powerful like lex/yacc. Or you might use a regular expression library like the PCRE library.

Comment: Any advice on the simple parser/tokenizer? I wrote a simple stack based machine language in C, and was thinking of extending it with multiple argument commands. I just don't have the capability to take in variable amounts of arguments at the moment.

Comment: The array doesn't have to resizable; it could have a cap and after that empty values...