# A way to get input of an int array in one scanf at once?

Tags: c

Is there away in which I can get input in one scanf where the user only needs to type a sequence of numbers (separated by something if needed like \n or' '). And it would be automatically stored in the array.   The same way there is a possibility in strings? 
Someone has mentioned to me . %d... with three dots that it's equivalent to %s both in scanf.  Is it true?

I haven't seen any similar questions.   I think they are simply talking about getting string array.   I am talking about int array at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq)

Comment: In what way are they similar to my question?   I am asking about getting multiple numbers and storing them in INT  array not string.   For example by using d with three dots.    Not sure how those questions you mentioned are related in any way.

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922159/variadic-scanf-in-c/6922290#6922290) useful?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but it looks like string.   Am asking about int array.   Thx.   Would appreciate help..

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to your question is no. (but I am wrong see below)

In C you really need to define everything very explicitly.

So if You want 5 numbers in an array you could

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", array[0], array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4]);
```

but this is fragile as if the format was not exactly that it would be difficult.

For what you want to achieve I would suggest reading in a whole line as a string and then processing the string to see how many numbers are in it and putting them in your array....

I am wrong in my initial assumption because since C99 there is this function called `vscanf`, which looks like it does exactly what you need.

I suggest you look at [this question which really goes through it for vscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017331/c99-vscanf-for-dummies), but for me I really think even `vscanf` could be a bit fragile and it would be better to read in data as string line by line using `fgets` to get data from `stdin` that will read everything into a string from the keyboard when you hit return provided the keyboard entry does not overflow the number of characters you indicate as a maximum - you can then use `sscanf` or other functions to scan through the string to pick up the numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for understanding what I am asking and answering to the point.  Only if you can add on something I was told which could be wrong totally.   That writing scanf  (%do. .. , arr) with three dots  and then typing sequence of numbers would enter them accordingly automatically in arr [0] arr [1] etc..   is it true or false? Thursday.

Comment: @bengy --- I think it is false -  I have never seen anything like it,,, but `vscanf` is something you should look at... I am editing my answer now

Comment: It is false. . .

Comment: Oh yeah thank you both.  Indeed I think it's false.  As to the vscanf it isn't clear to me.  But anyways.  Thank you.

Comment: Oh yeah thank you both.  Indeed I think it's false.  As to the vscanf it isn't clear to me.  But anyways.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily implement such a function yourself.

Let's steal the interface (mostly) from POSIX.1 [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), as it is known to work well. So:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

size_t get_ints(int **dataptr, size_t *sizeptr, FILE *in)
{
    int    *data;
    size_t  size, used = 0;
    int     value;

    /* Invalid parameters? None may be NULL. */
    if (!dataptr || !sizeptr || !in) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 0;
    }

    /* Has an error in the input stream already occurred? */
    if (ferror(in)) {
        errno = EIO;
        return 0;
    }

    /* Has data already been allocated? */
    if (!*dataptr || !*sizeptr) {
        /* No, not yet. */
        *dataptr = NULL;
        *sizeptr = 0;
    }
    data = *dataptr;
    size = *sizeptr;

    /* Read loop. */
    while (1) {

        /* Try reading one int. */
        if (fscanf(in, " %d", &value) != 1)
            break;

        /* Have one. Make sure data array has room for value. */        
        if (used >= size) {
            /* Reallocation policy. We need at least size = used + 1,
               but realloc() calls are relatively slow, so we want
               to allocate in larger chunks. This is just one typical
               policy. */
            if (used < 255)
                size = 256; /* Minimum allocation is 256 ints. */
            else
            if (used < 1048575)
                size = (3 * used) / 2;  /* Grow by 50% ... */
            else
                size = (used | 1048575) + 1048577; /* up to 1048576, after which round up to next multiple of 1048576. */

            data = realloc(data, size * sizeof data[0]);
            if (!data) {
                /* Note: original data in *data still exists! */
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return 0;
            }

            *dataptr = data;
            *sizeptr = size;
        }

        /* Append to array. */
        data[used++] = value;
    }

    /* An actual I/O error? */
    if (ferror(in)) {
        errno = EIO;
        return 0;
    }

    /* No, either an end of stream, or the next stuff
       in the stream is not an integer. 
       If used == 0, we want to ensure the caller knows
       there was no error. For simplicity, we avoid that
       check, and simply set errno = 0 always. */
    errno = 0;
    return used;
}
```

The interface to the above `get_ints()` function is simple: it takes a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, a pointer to the size (in ints) allocated for that array, and the stream handle, and returns the number of ints read from the stream. If an error occurs, it returns 0 with `errno` set to indicate the error. (`getline()` returns `-1` instead.)

If no error occurs, this particular implementation sets `errno = 0`, but do note that this behaviour is uncommon; normally, you can only expect `errno` to have a valid error number when the function returns the error code (usually -1, but zero for this function).

The way you use this function is very easy. For example, let's assume you want to read an array of ints from the standard input:

```
int main(void)
{
    int    *iarray = NULL; /* No array allocated yet, */
    size_t  isize  = 0;    /* so allocated size is zero, and */
    size_t  icount = 0;    /* no ints in it yet. */

    icount = get_ints(&iarray, &isize, stdin);
    if (!icount) {
        /* No ints read. Error? */
        if (errno)
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from standard input: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "No integers in standard input.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Read %zu integers from standard input.\n", icount);

    /*
     *  Do something with the integers...
    */

    /* Discard the dynamically allocated array. */
    free(iarray);
    iarray = NULL;
    isize  = 0;
    icount = 0;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that as long as you initialize your `iarray = NULL` and `isize = 0` when declaring it, the `get_ints()` function will allocate as much memory as is needed for the ints it reads. It is also then always safe to do `free(iarray); iarray = NULL; isize = 0;` to discard the array, even if `iarray` was NULL, because `free(NULL)` is safe to do (does nothing).

This is an excellent way of doing memory management in C. If you do it this way -- initialize your pointers to `NULL`, then `free()` them and reset them to `NULL` after they are no longer needed -- your programs won't have memory leaks or crash due to use-after-free or similar bugs. Many instructors won't bother, because they erroneously think that sort of carefulness can be tacked on later, *if necessary*.

(Do note, however, that even in the above program, in the error cases where the program is about to abort/exit/return, there is no such cleanup done. This is because the operating system will release all resources automatically. [Except for shared memory and filesystem objects.] Simply put, if your program is guaranteed to exit, it is not necessary to free dynamically allocated memory.)